# KVM&virt-manager-Error creating pool: Could not define storage pool: XML error:

Tags: kvm, virt-manager

Details

> Error creating pool: Could not define storage pool: XML error: name
> /home/shown/Documents cannot contain '/'
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/share/virtmanager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 89, in
> cb_wrapper
>
> callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)     File
> "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/createpool.py", line 442, in
>
> _async_pool_create
>
> poolobj = self._pool.install(create=True, meter=meter, build=build)
>
> File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/storage.py",line 543, in
> install
>
> raise RuntimeError(_("Could not define storage pool: %s") % str(e))
>
> RuntimeError: Could not define storage pool: XML error: name
>
> /home/shown/Documents cannot contain '/'

[image]

I really didn't catch the problem.
What's wrong?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Nice question. I have the same problem/

Comment: There is some configuration where the name of the storage pool is set to `/home/shown/Documents`, but the configuration is not shown in the question.